# jQuery Validation Plugin, addMethod change the element being validated value

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin and i've added my own rule to check our incident numbers. There have been various ways of users typing them in down the years and we try to recognise any way of doing it.

The official format is 0123S 230813

But users have been known to enter 123-S 230813 or 123-S-230813.

They are all valid, but the value I really want is the official one.

So i've created by own rule using the addMethod way that will validate all of the above and it works, but what i'd really like it to do on top is update the form element with the official format, if what the user has entered is correct. This is what i'm struggling with.

addMethod code below. I was hoping changing the element value and returning it would do the job but it doesn't seem too and from looking up this.optional(element) that isn't it's purpose.

So can I do this, or would I be better off just doing the formatting on the form .submit() and then just validating the regex in the validate plugin?

```
// ois incident number validator
jQuery.validator.addMethod("oisIncidentNo", function(value, element) {

var oisInc = value;
var validInc = false;

// strip spaces and dashes
oisInc = oisInc.replace(/ /g, '');
oisInc = oisInc.replace(/-/g, '');

// loop over the ois no and insert padded 0s at the front to make
// up the full correct number
if (oisInc.length<11 ){
    for(i=oisInc.length; i<11; i++ )
    {
        oisInc='0'+oisInc;
    }
}

// upper case it and put a space between the serial no and the date
oisInc=oisInc.toUpperCase();
oisInc=oisInc.substr(0, 5) + ' ' + oisInc.substr(5);    

// test the regex
validInc=/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/.test(oisInc);

// if the incident no is valid write the properly formatted one back
if (validInc) element.val(oisInc);

return this.optional(element) || validInc;
}, jQuery.format("Please enter a valid OIS Incident No format 1234S 270813."));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"So can I do this, or would I be better off just doing the formatting on the form .submit() and then just validating the regex in the validate plugin?"*

Have you tried it yet?  What happened?

I haven't tried this, but I imagine a scenario, where after you programatically change the element's value within your custom rule/method function, that it will trigger another validation test and enter into a loop.  Although you might be able to program around any infinite recursion... I just don't think it should be done like this.

I think it would be safer to simply validate the form's data from the user.  Then within the `submitHandler` callback function, re-factor the data just before sending it to the server.  This is more typical, IMO.  When the `submitHandler` callback function fires, the form has already passed validation so another validation test will not occur.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod("oisIncidentNo", function(value, element) {
        // your custom validation
    }, "Please enter a valid OIS Incident No format 1234S 270813.");

    $('#myform').validate({
        // your rules, options, and/or callback functions,
        rules: {
            myField: {
                oisIncidentNo: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // re-factor any data here
            // send data with an .ajax() or a form.submit()
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I did try it and it didn't work. So i've ended up implementing what you suggest above. I have a regex to validate all variations of the incident number, if that passes then I format it in the submit handler. thanks.